# Building a Promise array doesn't work but single promises do

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have a loop that calls a function that resolves a Promise and I need to call that multiple times.  When all calls have completed I then want to process all the promises' results.

I have an odd situation where if I take the call out of the loop, the Promise resolves and I can work with it in my Promise.all block.
But, if instead I call the function multiple times and .push into an array, I get an array of correct size but with no objects inside.

This without the loop works and I can see data in the geocodeResult object:

```
var geocodePromise = geocodeRows(parsed.data[0]);
Promise.all([geocodePromise]).then(function([geocodeResult]) {
    console.log("IN PROMISE: " + beautify(geocodeResult, null, 2, 80));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
})
.catch(function () {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

However, with a loop of calls:

```
var geocodeStack = [];
for(j=0; j<parsed.data.length; j++){
    geocodeStack.push(geocodeRows(parsed.data[j]));
}
console.log(beautify(geocodeStack, null, 2, 80));

Promise.all([geocodeStack]).then(function([geocodeResult]) {
    console.log("IN PROMISE: " + beautify(geocodeResult, null, 2, 80));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
})
.catch(function () {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

The console output looks like this:

```
IN PROMISE: [ {}, {} ]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you created two `catch` callbacks? You don't throw an error in the first `catch` callback, so the second one is not needed.

Comment: Also, in the first example, you don't need `Promise.all`, just use `geocodePromise.then(...`

Comment: Thanks - It's just because the code was stripped back for readability.  Agreed, I was just using Promise.all in both examples so it was comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `Promise.all([...geocodeStack])` or `Promise.all(geocodeStack)`.

You mixed two approaches and got `Promise.all([geocodeStack])` which passes an array of array into your `Promise.all`, not an array of Promises.

Comment: Just adding on to the answer. The point is, `geocodeStack` is already an array, so you don't need to wrap it in another array.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks Patrick. I added it in the line about passing array of array

Comment: Thank-you so much, I was tearing my hair out with that.  I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when SO lets me.